# Swift 3: How to return multiple data types

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Sorry if this is a noob question but I'm fairly new to swift.

I have a function that gets data from a webpage and saves it into a variable as a string. In the same function I also need to return an int, but I'm having issues returning them so I can use them outside the function. There is also an issue with the void return statement from the guard.

```
    func PageData(flag: Int, pageData: String) -> (Int?, String?)
{

    let URLString = url.text
    guard let myURL = URL(string: URLString!) else {
        print("invalid url")
        return
    }

    do {
        let pageData = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    let flag = 1

    return flag
    return pageData

}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Simply write like this return  (flag, pageData)

Comment: Beside of the mentioned possibilities there are others wich include errors but i would need to know where the `url.text` comes from to show.

Answer (score 4):

Your function must return a tuple, e.g.:

```
return (flag, pageData)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must return the object that the func itself returns so you should be returning the `(Int, String)` format.

This is how you would use it in your code:

```
func PageData(flag: Int, pageData: String) -> (Int?, String?) {

    let URLString = url.text
    guard let myURL = URL(string: URLString!) else {
        print("invalid url")
        return (nil, nil)
    }

    do {
        let pageData = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    let flag = 1

    return (flag, pageData)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return multiple values form a function like this

```
func PageData(flag: Int, pageData: String) -> (Int?, String?)
{

    let URLString = url.text
    guard let myURL = URL(string: URLString!) else {
        print("invalid url")
        return (nil, nil)
    }

    do {
        let pageData = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    let flag = 1

    return (flag, pageData)
}
```

Comment: You forgot about `return` in guard.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked.